# Trouble installing package from a PPA

Tags: 11.10, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

On Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit, I am trying to install a package update to fix the bug detailed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/774978).

In comment [*#25*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/774978/comments/25) Robert Hooker provides a [link](https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/sru3) for his package.

I have followed the instructions on the page for adding it to my repositories (both manually and from the terminal), and when I run sudo apt-get update I get this message at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch  ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/sru3/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/sru3/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I get and install these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package doesn't seem to be available for Ubuntu 11.10, only for some previous versions.
You can see for yourself [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/sru3/ubuntu/dists/).

To get these packages you need to manually modify your */etc/apt/sources.list* to include the older distro for this PPA. e.g.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/sru3/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sarvatt/sru3/ubuntu natty main
```

then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

*Note: This xorg fix may not work for you as it's intended for a different version of Ubuntu. You are better off asking the author for a fix that applies to your version.*

Comment: i see. what a pain. well I can at least try. So i just open up /etc/apt/sources.list and copy and paste the two urls at the bottom?